# How to add testimonials with an image?

Tags: theme-development, plugin-recommendation, development-strategy

Does anybody have an idea how to add testimonials with an image in WordPress? Is there is any plugin that fulfills my requirement? I searched but did not find any. It must support PHP version 4.4.9.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new category called **Testimonials** then, in your theme folder add a new file called **testimonials.php**.

Add this in the newly created file:

```
<div id="testimonials">
    <?php $args = array('caller_get_posts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 5);
    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'testimonial-image', true);
    ?>

        <div class="testimonail">
            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="" height="" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; else : endif; ?>
</div>
```

Then add  where do you want the testimonials to show. Example footer.php

Now you can add testimonials by simply adding a new post and fill it under the **Testimonials** category. As for the image, make a new custom field called **testimonial-image** and for the value add the path to the image (ex: http://example.com/image.png).

And you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for Reply,But I want to manage this testimonial separate from post.

Comment: Then install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ and add a new custom post type called Testimonials. Then use my code.

Comment: Hello thanks for reply I have created testimonial custom post type but i also need to show image for each testimonials.From this custom post type i m just able to insert title and content from where we can insert image .please let me know its very urgent

Comment: make a new custom field called testimonial-image and for the value add the path to the image (ex: http://example.com/image.png).

Comment: OK Thanks sir but my problem resolved .I have managed this through featured image.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will do everything you need and a whole lot more: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tb-testimonials/